# Drupal ubercart limited time offer

Tags: drupal, time, ubercart, cart

I am developing a web site with Drupal + Ubercart. I am using limited time offer module it works perfectly but when I add some product to cart before expiration time that product remains in the cart even it expires later. I think I have to use a trigger to make product removed from cart after expiration but I don't know how to do that. Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1):

In Ubercart's settings there is an option to control how long a cart is remembered. You could probably shorten that to less than a day and it should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, it can be used but that's not a perfect solution. User can add a product to cart 10 minutes before expiration. I need something that removes products from cart when they just expired.

Comment: You could probably use hook_form_alter to add a custom validation handler to the checkout form and stop the user from checking out with expired products. This would be done in a custom module.